# What is the equivalent to "fair use" in Europe?

Tags: copyright, fair-use

I'm preparing to publish an open source library.

In order to research local law, I wanted to know if there is an equivalent term for the USA "fair use" in European law?

Comment: Before this question was migrated, a knowledgeable member from the  [opensource.SE](https://opensource.stackexchange.com) pointed out the ["Right to Quote"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_quote) from the Berne Convention. Which does answer my question satisfactorily. (I will leave the question open to further, and more elaborate, contributions members may want to contribute.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The United Kingdom and common-law countries generally use the concept of [fair dealing](https://www.uleth.ca/lib/copyright/content/fair_dealing_week/fair_dealing_vs_fair_use.asp).

The EU doesn't really have a doctrine analogous to fair use. Instead, it has a list of explicitly permitted uses ([Article 5 of the Information Society Directive](https://www.ippt.eu/legal-texts/copyright-in-information-society-directive/article-5)), and its courts are generally very resistant to the adoption of fair-use analyses.